# Can't remove body in JS (box2d) processing

Tags: javascript, box2d, processing, physics, collision

I'm using Box2d with processing (JS), and I have two bodies, I want one of them to disappear when collision, I tried to use "physics.removeBody(b1);" but unfortunately all the bodies I have in my world disappear! this is the code in the collision function.

```
   void collision(Body b1, Body b2, float impulse) {
   if (b2 == basket && b1.getMass() > 0) {
   score += 10;
   pop.cue(0);
   pop.play();
   physics.removeBody(b1);
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the call for collision()? Perhaps all objects are meeting the conditions in if()...

Comment: I had a similar issue, and got around it by putting the bodies in ArrayLists and then removing the relevant element from the ArrayList when it was in a collision. A little clunky, but it works.

This might be orthogonal to your problem, but are you testing for '(b1 == basket && b2.getMass() > 0)' as well?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when creating bodies I do something like this:

```
void makeBody(float x, float y) {
    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bd.position.set(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(x, y));
    body = box2d.createBody(bd);
    body.setUserData(this); // This is important

    PolygonShape sd = new PolygonShape();
    float box2dW = box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(w/2);
    float box2dH = box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(h/2);  
    sd.setAsBox(box2dW, box2dH);    
    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.setUserData("box");

    // Attach Fixture to Body               
    body.createFixture(fd);
```

}

Now that your body has a userData property, you can test collision like so:

```
void beginContact (Contact cp) {

    // Get both fixtures
    Fixture f1 = cp.getFixtureA();
    Fixture f2 = cp.getFixtureB();
    // Get both bodies
    Body b1 = f1.getBody();
    Body b2 = f2.getBody();
    // Get our objects that reference these bodies
    Object o1 = b1.getUserData();
    Object o2 = b2.getUserData();

    //Detect player-enemy collision
    if (b1.getUserData() == "player" && b2.getUserData() == "enemy") {
      //... Do stuff here
    }
    if (b2.getUserData() == "player" && b1.getUserData() == "enemy") {
      //... Do stuff here
    }
```

The point is to use the body's setUserData() function to specify a unique identifier, then use the body's getUserData() function to check and make sure the object colliding is the one you intended. In your example, you have Body b1 and Body b2 but don't do any kind of testing to make sure that the correct bodies are colliding.

I hope this helps